# Split polyline by different lengths based on output

Tags: r, r-sf, polyline

I have multiple polylines that needs to be segemented to be a maximum of X feet while also not being shorter than Y feet.  See polyline example below.

```
df<-new("SpatialLinesDataFrame", data = structure(list(Count = "87", 
    length = 13443.0406016608, Lat_TC = 2.5), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    lines = list(new("Lines", Lines = list(new("Line", coords = structure(c(1279653.38073649, 
    1275804.03323203, 476893.543169454, 489773.677656633), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L)))), ID = "1")), bbox = structure(c(1275804.03323203, 
    476893.543169454, 1279653.38073649, 489773.677656633), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
        projargs = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31 +lon_0=-104.333333333333 +k=0.999909091 +x_0=165000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs"))
```

```
#Segment polyline function

CreateSegment <- function(coords, from, to) {
  distance <- 0
  coordsOut <- c()
  biggerThanFrom <- F
  for (i in 1:(nrow(coords) - 1)) {
    d <- sqrt((coords[i, 1] - coords[i + 1, 1])^2 + (coords[i, 2] - coords[i + 
                                                                             1, 2])^2)
    distance <- distance + d
    if (!biggerThanFrom && (distance > from)) {
      w <- 1 - (distance - from)/d
      x <- coords[i, 1] + w * (coords[i + 1, 1] - coords[i, 1])
      y <- coords[i, 2] + w * (coords[i + 1, 2] - coords[i, 2])
      coordsOut <- rbind(coordsOut, c(x, y))
      biggerThanFrom <- T
    }
    if (biggerThanFrom) {
      if (distance > to) {
        w <- 1 - (distance - to)/d
        x <- coords[i, 1] + w * (coords[i + 1, 1] - coords[i, 1])
        y <- coords[i, 2] + w * (coords[i + 1, 2] - coords[i, 2])
        coordsOut <- rbind(coordsOut, c(x, y))
        break
      }
      coordsOut <- rbind(coordsOut, c(coords[i + 1, 1], coords[i + 1, 
                                                               2]))
    }
  }
  return(coordsOut)
}


CreateSegments <- function(coords, length = 10000, n.parts = 0) {
  stopifnot((length > 0 || n.parts > 0))
  # calculate total length line
  total_length <- 0
  for (i in 1:(nrow(coords) - 1)) {
    d <- sqrt((coords[i, 1] - coords[i + 1, 1])^2 + (coords[i, 2] - coords[i + 
                                                                             1, 2])^2)
    total_length <- total_length + d
  }
  
  # calculate stationing of segments
  if (length > 0) {
    stationing <- c(seq(from = 0, to = total_length, by = length), total_length)
  } else {
    stationing <- c(seq(from = 0, to = total_length, length.out = n.parts), 
                    total_length)
  }
  
  # calculate segments and store the in list
  newlines <- list()
  for (i in 1:(length(stationing) - 1)) {
    newlines[[i]] <- CreateSegment(coords, stationing[i], stationing[i + 
                                                                       1])
  }
  return(newlines)
}


MergeLast <- function(lst) {
  l <- length(lst)
  lst[[l - 1]] <- rbind(lst[[l - 1]], lst[[l]])
  lst <- lst[1:(l - 1)]
  return(lst)
}


SegmentSpatialLines <- function(sl, length = 0, n.parts = 0, merge.last = FALSE) {
  stopifnot((length > 0 || n.parts > 0))
  id <- 0
  newlines <- list()
  sl <- as(sl, "SpatialLines")
  for (lines in sl@lines) {
    for (line in lines@Lines) {
      crds <- line@coords
      # create segments
      segments <- CreateSegments(coords = crds, length, n.parts)
      if (merge.last && length(segments) > 1) {
        # in case there is only one segment, merging would result into error
        segments <- MergeLast(segments)
      }
      # transform segments to lineslist for SpatialLines object
      for (segment in segments) {
        newlines <- c(newlines, Lines(list(Line(unlist(segment))), ID = as.character(id)))
        id <- id + 1
      }
    }
  }
  return(SpatialLines(newlines))
}
```

I would like to split this polyline every 6000 feet, however if the last line segment is shorter than 6000, combine with previous line and split combined line in half.

```
split_poly=st_as_sf(SegmentSpatialLines(x,length=6000,merge.last = T))
```

This creates two line segments and I would like to split the second line segment in half since it is larger than 6000 feet. End result would be three line segments with a length of 6000, 3721 and 3721.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using below loop

```
datalist= list()
for (i in 1:nrow(split_poly)) {
  
 if(st_drop_geometry(split_poly[i,"length"])<6000) next
if(st_drop_geometry(split_poly[i,"length"])>6000){
  split_poly2=st_as_sf(SegmentSpatialLines(as_Spatial(split_poly[i,]),n.parts=3,merge.last = F))
split_poly2=split_poly2%>%mutate(length=st_length(xx),id=i)
 datalist[[i]] <- xx # add it to your list
  
}
  
}

final_df=do.call(rbind,datalist)
```